# python opencv webcam dosn't shows anything

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to make an screen recording program with interface in it, using opencv and tkinter.
I'm intending to make it both presentation and cam recorded. so I made a window which displays my cam, inside the screnn recording frame.
I think I'm almost there, but my webcam displays nothing. recording works fine, though.
Can I get some help? I've searched for this, but I don't see a solution for me.
thank you :)
I think this part of the code makes problem :

```
    resolution = (1920,1080)
    codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    filename = '{}.avi'.format(file_name.get())
    location = save_dest.get()
    fps = 60.0
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(location+'/'+filename, codec, fps, resolution)
    cv2.namedWindow('Cam', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)    
    cv2.resizeWindow('Cam', 480, 270)
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

   while record:
     res, frame_cam = cam.read()
     if res:
        cv2.imshow('Cam', frame_cam)
     img = pyautogui.screenshot() 
     frame = np.array(img) 
     frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) 
     out.write(frame)     
    
     if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):                       
        break

out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: When I copied and tried your code, it works fine. WHat do you mean by saying "my webcam displays nothing" ? DOest it give any error ?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk
I mean the 'Cam' frame dosn't show anything except just a grey screen. If it works fine on yours, then I guess problem  is my laptop..
Is there a way to allow the program access to the cam?

Comment: You may try to run your webcam with a simple `VideoCapture` example to see it works fine or not.

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk Thank you for your advice! But can I ask you just one more thing?
Trying 'VideoCapture' gives me an error '!_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'.
I've searched about it, and they say this error occurs when program can't find the location of image or something like that.
But can webcam have this 'location' too? I don't really get it.

Comment: it seems it can not open your camera. first try to run your camera then your problem will disappear